# Ad is too pixelated

Tags: discussion, advertising

[image: Ad]

A koala wearing sunnies hanging from a palm tree on an island is a 100% accurate and dangarang representation of Sydney. I don't have any problems with that.

However, the text "Join a world class engineering team in Sydney" looks awful, as does the logo in the bottom left hand corner.

I couldn't see any way to give feedback to the ad.

I'm on Google Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) on OSX 10.13.2 (17C88).

The company advertising it seems to be Canva:

[image]

Comment: *I couldn't see any way to give feedback to the ad*.  I think you just found a way.

Comment: I like it. It makes me know I would NOT accept a graphics design position from them because they obviously don't pay their people enough

Comment: @DavyM they only promised world class engineering, not world class UX.

Comment: Maybe the pixels are melting from Aussie sun.

Comment: @DanFromGermany: That'd make them less sharp, not sharper.

Comment: @DavyM Perhaps they _need_ a graphics designer, and this ad is the cry for help?

Comment: Is the PNG a copy of the actual ad, or a screenshot of how it rendered for you?

Comment: I agree, it looks awful: what on Earth possessed them to leave the hyphen out of "world-class"?

Comment: I would say that any publicity is good publicity for the company but seeing as I can't see the company name due to pixelation, I don't think it counts in this instance :)

Comment: Just downvote and move on

Comment: This is just another case of people designing on HiDPI/Retina screens forgetting that not everybody uses them...

Comment: Only accept ads as SVG. Problem solved.

Comment: @TomášZato: ...except then people will start to [embed images in SVGs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6250418/1461424).

Comment: @Krumia SVGs as `<img>` cannot load external resources or run scripts.